# Header in wrong alphabet

Tags: header-footer, alphabet

how do I avoid my headings to change alphabet?

these are the packages I'm using which I think are involved:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx} 
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,german,greek,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\footnotesize{\foreignlanguage{italian}{\leftmark}}}

\fancyfoot{} % clear all fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Saffo, Tucidide, Plutarco e la peste ad Atene}
Per cominciare la \textgreek{φωνῆς ἐπίσχεσις} (Plut, Demetr. 38.4) può essere accostata a \textgreek{ἥ τε φάρυγξ καὶ ἡ γλῶσσα εὐθὺς αἱματώδη ἦν καὶ πνεῦμα ἄτοπον καὶ δυσῶδες ἠφίει·} (Thuc. 2.48.3); l'\textgreek{ἐρύθημα πυρῶδες} di Plutarco e \textgreek{ἐρυθήματα καὶ φλόγωσις} di Tucidide sono difficilmente distinguibili, come anche il riferimento di questi a \textgreek{τῶν ὀφθαλμῶν}, che abbiamo anche in Plutarco (\textgreek{ὄψεων ὑπολείψεις}). Anche l' \textgreek{ἱδρῶτες ὀξεῖς} che colpisce Antioco si ritrova senza fatica in Tucidide 2.49, dove leggiamo \textgreek{ὕδωρ ψυχρὸν σφᾶς αὐτοὺς ῥίπτειν} ed è difficile da dimenticare nella descrizione di Tucidide\index[n]{Tucidide} quella che Demetrio chiama \textgreek{ἀταξία καὶ θόρυβος ἐν τοῖς σφυγμοῖς}, per esempio dove l'ateniese dice di come \textgreek{τὴν καρδίαν στηρίξειεν, ἀνέστρεφέ τε αὐτὴν καὶ ἀποκαθάρσεις χολῆς […] σπασμὸν ἐνδιδοῦσα ἰσχυρόν [...] τὸ μὲν ἔξωθεν ἁπτομένῳ σῶμα} (Thuc. 2.49), senza voler citare l'intera sezione sull'\textgreek{ἀθυμία} degli Ateniesi e sulle sue conseguenze. Si sente l'eco della tragedia psicologica, nel cupo finale della breve descrizione di Plutarco\index[n]{Plutarco} (\textgreek{τέλος δὲ τῆς ψυχῆς κατὰ κράτος ἡττημένης ἀπορία καὶ θάμβος καὶ ὠχρίασις;} cfr. e.g. Thuc. 2.49, \textgreek{ἡ νόσος ἀκμάζοι, οὐκ ἐμαραίνετο, ἀλλ’ ἀντεῖχε παρὰ δόξαν τῇ ταλαιπωρίᾳ, ὥστε ἢ διεφθείροντο οἱ πλεῖστοι}). Il tema della vittoria del male sulla mente e sullo spirito è ben noto al lettore di Tucidide\index[n]{Tucidide} ed è stato più volte sottolineato, sin da Parry\footnote{Da un punto di vista linguistico e grammaticale Parry 1969, 115.}, insieme al lessico metaforico della battaglia in cui gli Ateniesi sono
sconfitti. La peste rientra tra i \textgreek{παθήματα} della guerra a pieno titolo. 

Questi sei elementi elencati da Erasistrato\index[n]{Erasistrato} in Plutarco\index[n]{Plutarco} sono facilmente individuabili nel fr. 31 Voigt di Saffo\index[n]{Saffo} ma, anche in questo caso, è opportuno riprenderli, perché il testo di Saffo\index[n]{Saffo} in questione è stato oggetto di revisioni molto recenti. Il testo a cui faccio riferimento è l'edizione di Hutchinson, ma con la proposta di Livrea per la soluzione delle \textit{cruces} al v. 13\footnote{Neri-Citti 2005, 51-62 (spec. 54 e 57) hanno offerto una raffinata e documentatissima analisi con una proposta alternativa per questo verso. Si vedano anche Aloni 1997, 64 n.1. Di Benedetto 1985, 151s.;   Di Benedetto 2010, 1-2, e Hutchinson 2001, 174, nonché Ferrari 2007, 159s. Lo Spengel nel 1828 espunse \textgreek{ψυχρὸς} e la lezione \textgreek{ἀ δέ μ’ἴδρως κακχέεται} si diffuse. L'altra versione, ottenuta con i due testimoni, era \textgreek{έκαδε δ’ἱδρῶς ψυχρὸς κακχέεται} ma, come ricorda Livrea, Page criticò questa vulgata proponendo a sua volta una soluzione poco convincente. Livrea recupera “la vecchia idea di Schneidewin (1836) che \textgreek{κακ} sia glossa per \textgreek{κακός} poi penetrata nel testo” e si concentra su una delle prime critiche, \textgreek{ἴδρως} al femminile. Ipotizzando un errore di lettura \textgreek{ψυχρὰ} per \textgreek{ψῦχρα} propone la lezione adottata qui.}

\bigskip
\begin{quotation}
{\small 
\textgreek{
\begin{verse}
\poemlines{4}
\begin{altverse}
φαίνεταί μοι κῆνος ἴσος θέοισιν \\
ἔμμεν’ ὤνηρ ὄττις ἐνάντιός τοι \\
ἰσδάνει καὶ πλάσιον ἆδυ φωνεί\\σας ὐπακούει \\
\end{altverse}
\begin{altverse}
καὶ γελαίσας ἰμέροεν· τό μ’ ἦ μὰν \\
καρδίαν ἐν στήθεσιν ἐπτόαισεν, \\
ὠς γὰρ  \Ladd{ἔς} σ’ ἴδω βρόχε’ ὤς με φώνησ’\\
οὐδὲν ἔτ’ εἴκει,\\
\end{altverse}
\begin{altverse}
ἀλλὰ κὰμ μὲν γλῶσσα \crux ἔαγε \crux, λέπτον \\
δ’ αὔτικα χροῖ πῦρ ὐπαδεδρόμακεν, \\
ὀππάτεσσι δ’ οὐδὲν ὄρημμ’, ἐπιρρόμ\\βεισι δ’ ἄκουαι,\\
\end{altverse}
\begin{altverse}
Ψῦχρα δ’ἴδρως κακχέεται, τρόμος δέ \\
παῖσαν ἄγρει, χλωροτέρα δὲ ποίας\\
ἔμμι, τεθνάκην δ’ ὀλίγω ’πιδεύης \\
φαίνομ’ ἔμ’ αὔται· \\
\end{altverse}
\begin{altverse}
ἀλλὰ πὰν τόλματον ἐπεὶ \crux καὶ πένητα \crux \\
\end{altverse}
\end{verse}}


(Saffo fr. 31 Voigt\indexp{Saffo!fr.31 Voigt|qt})
}
\end{quotation}


\bigskip
\end{document}
```

I get what I want, but sometimes instead of having this result:
[image]

I get this :

[image]

Can anybody help me on how to fix this, please?

Comment: Please expand your example into a full [MWE (minimum working example)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that actually recreates the problem you're looking to fix. Please be sure to indicate any `\selectlanguage{...}` instructions you may be executing ahead of `\chapter` commands.

Comment: You might try a font selection in your `\fancyhead` command: `\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rmfamily\footnotesize{\leftmark}}`. If the output routine is called while the greek font is active, the heading will be in that font. The same is true for `\fancyfoot`.

Comment: Thank you: I have updated the sample with enough for the problem to show up. I have tried \rmfamily and selectlanguage but I must have done something wrong. Please, can you see where is my mistake? thank you very much!

Comment: @PietroMariaLiuzzo The example is not compilable. It chokes at `\poemlines`; if I add the `verse` package it stops at `\Ladd`, at `\crux`, at `\indexp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `utf8x`, at least until it is updated; prefer `utf8`.

The problem is due to the page break when LaTeX is typesetting Greek verses.

Just use

```
\fancyhead{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\leftmark}

\fancyfoot{} % clear all fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\thepage}
```

so that the headers and footers will be typeset in the correct encoding.

I suggest you to define a `greekverse` environment:

```
\newenvironment{greekverse}
 {\greektext\verse}
 {\endverse}
```

so that you can type

```
\begin{quotation}
\begin{greekverse}
\poemlines{4}
\begin{altverse}
φαίνεταί μοι κῆνος ἴσος θέοισιν \\
ἔμμεν’ ὤνηρ ὄττις ἐνάντιός τοι \
[...]

\begin{altverse}
ἀλλὰ πὰν τόλματον ἐπεὶ \crux καὶ πένητα \crux \\
\end{altverse}
\end{greekverse}

(Saffo fr. 31 Voigt\indexp{Saffo!fr.31 Voigt|qt})
\end{quotation}
```